# Typescript (Ionic 3/Angular) string replace url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Trying to get this easy thing working but can't find it out...

I've got this url that looks like this:

```
https://website.com/image{width}x{height}.jpg
```

Now I need to replace the `{width}` and the `{height}` values.

I tried this function but I get the following error message all the time:

```
placeThumb(thumb:String){
  thumb = thumb.replace('{width}', '300');
  thumb = thumb.replace('{height}', '150');
  return thumb;
}
```

The error code I'm getting is:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   at PlayerPage.webpackJsonp.109.PlayerPage.placeThumb (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:202:23)
>   at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/PlayerPage.ngfactory.js:166:26)
>   at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15109:21)
>   at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14223:14)
>   at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14569:21)
>   at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14501:13)
>   at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14224:5)
>   at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15472:42)
>   at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15009:12)
>   at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11993:22)

I think it should be really simple but maybe I am missing something.

HTML is looking as follows:

```
<ion-card>
  <img [src]="placeThumb(playerData.twitch_thumb)"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
     <ion-icon name="logo-twitch" class="iconblink"></ion-icon> Streaming: {{playerData.twitch_title}}
    </ion-card-title>
    <p>
      {{ playerData.twitch_thumb }}
      {{ placeThumb(playerData.twitch_thumb) }}
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: `thumb` is undefined. Where is `thumb` coming from?

Comment: Thats the strange thing, it isn't.
Its called from html `{{ placeThumb(playerData.twitch_thumb) }}`

When I do it like the following, it does work. But it only replaced one value as you can see: 

`placeThumb(thumb){
     return thumb && thumb.replace('{height}', '150');
  }`

Comment: have you tried thimb.toString().replace('{width}', '300'); ??

Comment: So, what's the **initial value** of `playerData.twitch_thumb`? Also, I personally would avoid to use a **method** in angular to **display data**. Either use a getter, either alter the value. If you're going to display many items with that criteria, you may encounter performance issues, since the value will be evaluated endlessly.

Comment: @JesseH - please show your full HTML to help us help you. Have you tried using Augury to see the data in the HTML?

Comment: Added html code. I'm not familiar with Augury but I may have to try out using a pipe?

Comment: No pipe is needed here. If you want to take my two cents, take care of `playerData`. The only issue can be there, since you're looking for a property of that object specifically. There isn't any other relevant part in your code that shouldn't work, I'm just curious about where that variable is coming from, since the issue is likely there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue was. Because this code only have to load once on page load I managed to run the function on the ts file and assign it to a variable.

So from .TS i'm running it like:

```
twitchThumb:any;

getPlayerInfo(){
   let twthumb = 'https://website.com/image{width}x{height}.jpg';
   this.twitchThumb = this.placeThumb(twthumb);
}

placeThumb(thumb){
   thumb = thumb.replace('{width}', '300');
   thumb = thumb.replace('{height}', '150');
    return thumb;
}
```

And on the HTML I simply call `{{ twitchThumb }}`

Thanks all for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work. I am unable to reproduce the issue mentioned above. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7eh1pp) is the working demo.